# Multiple step definition found for specflow feature steps

Tags: specflow, feature-selection

I have two feature files with some same scenarios. when i create definitions for them the first feature1.cs file has all the steps. when i click on the second feature file and generate definition it reuses some functions from the first feature1.cs file, as some scenarios are duplicate.

Now i have a `[BeforeScenario]` for both the file. But when i run the second feature file, it ends up using the `[BeforeScenario]` of the first file.

I noticed that the Binding tag in the feature1.cs file had the names of both of my feature file like

```
[Binding, Scope(Feature = "feature1"), Scope(Feature="feature2")]
```

So i removed second feature2 and placed it in my feature2.cs file.

Now, i am able to run the `[BeforeFeature]` from feature2.cs but when i click on scenario step and go to defination it says "Multiple Steps found" inspite of all the reusable steps being in the feature1.cs file itself.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please post examples of the steps that it thinks are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to realize is that all step definitions in specflow are global. To illustrate that, lets say I have 3 files: Feature1.feature, Feature2.feature and myStepDefs.cs.

In myStepDefs.cs I have the following code:

```
[Given(@"I have asked a new question")]
public void GivenIHaveAskedANewQuestion{
   //Some Code
}
```

Now in my feature1 file I have this Scenario

```
Scenario: I ask a question and get a bad answer
Given I have asked a new question
When I get an answer
And this answer is not helpful
Then I should Downvote this answer 
And I should explain why it does not help answer my question
```

and In my feature2 file I have this Scenario

```
Scenario: I ask a question and get a good answer
Given I have asked a new question
When I get an answer
And this answer is helpful
Then I should upvote this answer 
And I should mark this answer as accepted
```

In this case we reuse the given step, but we only need 1 step definition, not one for each feature.

Now you also explain that you have 2 `[BeforeScenario]` StepDefs. These run before EVERY Scenario, so if they do the same thing, again you only need one. If they do different things and you only want them to run before a given Feature/Scenario, then I would recommend you have a look at [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings), what you need to do is assign scope to these bindings so that it looks like this:

```
 [BeforeScenario, Scope(//your scope)]
```

this way the BeforeScenario steps only run for their given scope

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess i should had mentioned the fact that i am aware of the reusablity function of specflow. The issue that i was facing was that i was getting an error saying "Multiple steps found" when there were no multiple steps.
As i've mentioned in my comment, the Binding issues was also fixed when i changed the scope. But then again i was getting Multiple steps found issue.

Comment: Could you show us your file structure, the files you are having the issue with, and the code in each of those files that is having the issue before you made any changes. Thanks